# how to stop recycler view from repeating for loop items before actual result?

Tags: for-loop, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, duplicates

I have a nested recycler view which takes its data from firebase. there is a for loop that runs in an attempt to get all sets of the same exercise into one card. The loop seems to be working fine, however, the recycler view shows the entire process of the for loop. for example, if there is three items to be added to one card, it shows three cards with the third card being the actual result desired and the first two not desired(So the first card has 1, the second has 2 and the third card would have the actual 3). I tried adding a clear function and it produces my desired result, however only once, and is replaced if I try to add a new exercise.

```
 private fun initRecycler() {
    val date = Calendar.getInstance().time
    val currentTime = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US).format(date)
    recyclerView = findViewById<SuperRecyclerView>(R.id.rv_sync)
    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)
    recyclerView!!.setLayoutManager(layoutManager)
    adapter = ParentAdapter(
        ArrayList()//mutableListOf<ParentModel>()
    )

    recyclerView.adapter = adapter


    val syncedWorkOutReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        .child("Synced Workouts").child(userIds).child(currentTime)

    //TODO this is the code that needs fixing*********************



    syncedWorkOutReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {

            val addedIds = mutableListOf<String>()
            val parents = mutableListOf<ParentModel>()


            for (word in p0.children) {


//      (parents as ArrayList<ParentModel>).clear()  ---- this produces the desired result, but shows only one card which is replaced if i try adding another. 

                val sets = word.getValue(FbTrackData::class.java)
                val children = mutableListOf<ChildModel>()
                for (word1 in p0.children) {
                    val sets1 = word1.getValue(FbTrackData::class.java)
                    if (sets1!!.exercise == sets!!.exercise && !addedIds.contains(
                            sets.setId
                        )
                    ) {
                        addedIds.add(sets1.setId)
                        val child = ChildModel(sets1.weight, sets1.reps)
                        children.add(child)
                    }
                }
                val parent = ParentModel(
                    sets!!.exercise,
                    children
                )
                if (parent.children.isNotEmpty()) {
                    parents.add(parent)

                }

            }
            adapter.setParents(parents)

        }



        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

        }

    })

}
```

image of the wrong result:
https://ibb.co/tH0GyzB

image of desired result: (happens with clear function added, but is replaced on new items added):
https://ibb.co/5BdWGfw

in the desired result image, I achieved that by adding a clear function inside the for loop, however, it causes the card to be replaced if I add a new exercise. when the clear is removed, it produces the undesired result in the other image. how should I work this loop?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by changing the way I sent the data to the adapters. instead of sending a parent model which contained the title and the child model (Containing the weights and reps), I simply sent an array list of the titles to the adapter, and then in the parent adapter, I queried firebase to get the second set of data to match to the titles and sent it to the child adapter from there.